# how to get two more lines in textfile

Tags: c#

i have following code i want this line and next 2 below lines how do this any idea. please help,i want last number please see text below.

```
static void Main()
{
    int counter = 0; string line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"E:\file\log.txt"))
    {
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()))
            {         
                sb.AppendLine(line.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

***** INCOMING CALL: 25/04/2016 - 11:45 *****

NAME: Test

NUMBER: (425) 555-1212

***** INCOMING CALL: 25/04/2016 - 11:45 *****

NAME: Test2

NUMBER: (425) 544-1213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 static void Main()
        {
            int counter = 0; string line;

            List<string> ss = new List<string>();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"E:\file\log.txt"))
            {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    if (line.Contains(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()))
                    {
                        ss.Add(line);                     
                        line = file.ReadLine();
                        if (line != null)

                            ss.Add(line);
                        line = file.ReadLine();
                        if (line != null)                           
                            ss.Add(line);

                    }
                }
            }

            var item = ss.LastOrDefault();            
            string number = item.Substring(0, 24).Replace("NUMBER:", "").Trim();
            Console.WriteLine(number);
            Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just call file.ReadLine two more times, but it is important to check if the returned string is null because you could reach an unexpected end of file and your code is no more protected by the check in the while condition

```
...
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"E:\file\log.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()))
        {

            sb.AppendLine(line);
            line = file.ReadLine();
            if(line != null) sb.AppendLine(line);
            line = file.ReadLine();
            if(line != null) sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to get just the last three lines (assuming that your file is well formatted) then you could add a reset of the StringBuilder inside the loop

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"E:\file\log.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()))
        {
            // This will remove the previous data and keep 
            // just the last three lines.....
            sb.Length = 0;
            sb.AppendLine(line);
            line = file.ReadLine();
            if(line != null) sb.AppendLine(line);
            line = file.ReadLine();
            if(line != null) sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

In alternative, but I am not sure if this is a good idea from a performance point of view (in particular if we are talking of a large file), we could use linq in this way

```
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                File.ReadLines(@"E:\file\log.txt").Reverse().Take(3));
```

Comment: i want last one how to get this

Comment: Sorry, I have not understood your comment